# Convert animation node result into editable object

Tags: animation-nodes

Is there a way to convert an animation nodes result into an object?

For example, animations nodes are used to generate the face of a clock. I want to convert that result into an object that can edited. Is there a setting or procedure that will do this conversion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the time you can simply copy the output of Animation Nodes in the viewport and continue to work on that copy. The node tree that created the object can be deactivated.